# How to use Jmeter with Docker in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: image, docker, jmeter, virtual-machine

I am working on Jmeter, that I have to install in a Virtual Machine. To install applications, we usually use Docker. Thus, I'd like to know if it's possible to install in my Virtual Machine the Jmeter application.

I have tried to run a lot of Docker Images but I can't understand anything about it... I tried to run and pull with docker this image : https://hub.docker.com/r/justb4/jmeter/ but when I tried to run it, I can't on GUI mode...

The thing is that I have a test plan test.jmx that I worked on in my PC, and I would like to create it in my VM (with the GUI Jmeter mode) or to export it in my VM so that I could launch it.

I don't know if anyone could help me!

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

> To install applications, we usually use Docker.

this is very weird use case for Docker.

If you want to use Docker for running JMeter in GUI mode for tests development I doubt that you will be able to find a suitable image in the [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/), most probably you will need to build one yourself, an example [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) would be something like:

```
FROM alpine:edge

ENV DISPLAY :99
ENV RESOLUTION 1366x768x24

RUN  echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache curl xfce4-terminal xvfb x11vnc xfce4 openjdk8-jre bash xrdp \
    && curl -L https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz >  /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && tar -xvf /tmp/jmeter.tgz -C /opt \
    && rm /tmp/jmeter.tgz \
    && curl -L https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ > /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar \
    && echo "[Globals]" > /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "bitmap_cache=true" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "bitmap_compression=true" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "autorun=jmeter" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "[jmeter]" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "name=jmeter" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "lib=libvnc.so" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "ip=localhost" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "port=5900" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "username=jmeter" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini \
    && echo "password=" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

EXPOSE 5900
EXPOSE 3389

CMD ["bash", "-c", "rm -f /tmp/.X99-lock && rm -f /var/run/xrdp.pid\
 && nohup bash -c \"/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 ${RESOLUTION} -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset && export DISPLAY=99 > /dev/null 2>&1 &\"\
  && nohup bash -c \"startxfce4 > /dev/null 2>&1 &\"\
   && nohup bash -c \"x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :99 -forever -bg -nopw -rfbport 5900 > /dev/null 2>&1\"\
    && nohup bash -c \"xrdp -p 3389 > /dev/null 2>&1\"\
     && nohup bash -c \"/opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/./jmeter -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform > /dev/null 2>&1 &\"\
      && tail -f /dev/null"]
```

1. Save the above Dockerfile somewhere on your local drive
2. [Build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the image like:

   ```
   docker build -t jmeter:gui .
   ```
3. Run the image like:

   ```
   docker run -d -p 3389:3389 -p 5900:5900 jmeter:gui
   ```
4. You should be able to connect to the GUI of the running image using [RDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-clients) or [VNC](https://www.geckoandfly.com/23203/vnc-client-viewer-windows-mac-linux/) client

For running your JMeter tests in Docker refer to [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how) article